# set image width of a series of images

Tags: jquery, html, image

I have the following problem I have a container that has a certain width. In that container are a serie of images. Some are larger than the container some are smaller. Now i want the largest image to be 80% of the container and all the other images need to be resized, according to that one largest image (only if they are bigger than the container).

This is what i've tried so far:

```
var $pageContainer = $('.pageContainer');
        var canvasWidth = $pageContainer.width();
        var maxWidth = 0;

        $pageContainer.find('img').each(function (index, el) {
            if ($(el).width() > maxWidth) maxWidth = $(el).width();
        });

        var percentage = canvasWidth / maxWidth * 100;

        $pageContainer.find('img').each(function () {
            var $img = $(this);
            var imgWidth = $img.width();

            $img.width(percentage + '%');
        });
```

Offcourse this isnt working. cause if the percentage variable is 64 then the image is just getting resized to 64% of its container. So i think i should just take the largest image, set it to 80%, and calculate the difference, but i have no idea where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there! You were setting a % value depending on the width of the container (as you mentioned). So instead, apply the percentage to the current image width.

The fourth image (in my example) is the largest. The rest will resize depending on the resize of the fourth image.

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ks7QU/1/)

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/ks7QU/2/) that checks if the biggest image is larger than the container.

```
    var $pageContainer = $('.pageContainer');
    var canvasWidth = $pageContainer.width();
    var maxWidth = 0;

    $pageContainer.find('img').each(function (index, el) {
        if ($(el).width() > maxWidth) maxWidth = $(el).width();
    });


    var percentage = canvasWidth / maxWidth;

    $pageContainer.find('img').each(function () {
        var $img = $(this);
        var imgWidth = $img.width();

        $img.width(imgWidth * percentage);
    });
```